# Не прогружается фотография

Tags: html, yandex-maps-api

Столкнулся с такой ситуацией: нужно вставить фотографию в текст метки, но в конченом итоге именно эта фотография не прогружается.

Вот код - `<br>[![][5]][5]</br>`.

Вот сама фотка - http://safe-rgs.ru/uploads/posts/2018-05/1526887785_dsc_0663.jpg .

Пробовал найти похожие, но и они не загружаются. Что делать ?

[image: код + нужная фотка]

[image: итог+ нужная]

[image: код + не нужная]

[image: итог + не нужная]

Comment: Попробовала с вашим примером кода и этой же фоткой. Отобразилась при вставке интерактивной карты на jsfiddle. 
Если фотка не отображается на Яндекс.Картах по ссылке, то тут дело в ограничениях со стороны Карт - там из соображений безопасности не подгружаются ресурсы пользовательских карт. Картинка будет только при вставке карты Конструктора на сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Вы ошиблись с тегом.
`<br>` - непарный тег переноса строки, а вы его сделали парным. Уберите его неверную реализацию

```
<img src="http://safe-rgs.ru/uploads/posts/2018-05/1526887785_dsc_0663.jpg">
```

...и картинка отобразится:

https://jsfiddle.net/Coroner1st/d3rsqjnf/1/

В режиме редактирования карты и при доступе по ссылке картинки не отображаются, но станут видны после добавления кода карты на сайт. Такое ограничение Яндекс трактует требованиями безопасности.

Comment: Я убрал этот тег, но это никак не повлияло на ситуацию. Я уже попробовал сделать другую метку, другую карту, но всё равно, фотография не появляется.
Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Обратите внимание, фотографии видны только при интеграции карты на сайт. По прямой ссылке на карту фотографии не будет.